# forms and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I'm creating a simple form for a site I manage. I use jQuery for my JavaScript.  I noticed a large amount of plugins for jQuery and forms.  Does anybody have any favorites that they find especially useful?  In particular, plugins to help with validation would be the most useful.

Answer (score 5):

The jQuery [Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) is pretty much standard. It handles serializing form fields and AJAX submission.

Answer (score 2):

[Form Validation](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate) is one that comes to my mind. I think is being used here in SO.